# numpy : How to convert an array type quickly

Tags: python, numpy

I find the astype() method of numpy arrays not very efficient. I have an array containing
3 million of Uint8 point. Multiplying it by a 3x3 matrix takes 2 second, but converting the result from uint16 to uint8 takes another second.

More precisely :

```
    print time.clock()
    imgarray = np.dot(imgarray,  M)/255
    print time.clock()
    imgarray = imgarray.clip(0, 255)
    print time.clock()
    imgarray = imgarray.astype('B')
    print time.clock()
```

dot product and scaling takes 2 sec
clipping takes 200 msec
type conversion takes 1 sec

Given the time taken by the other operations, I would expect `astype` to be faster.
Is there a faster way to do type conversion, or am I wrong when guesstimating that type conversion should not be that hard ?

Edit : the goal is to save the final 8 bit array to a file

Comment: Why do you need to go to uint16 and back again? Is it possible to have `M` as a uint8 matrix, then you don't need the conversion.

Comment: the result of the dot product will exceed the uint8 range. I originally was using a float M matrix, and thought going to integer would give me some improvement, but this is not true.

Comment: What takes all that time, probably, is accessing all the memory locations. Sounds hard to fix.

Comment: But clipping is also accessing all memory locations, yet it is fast.
Hopefully clipping does not need to modify a lot of locations.
Similar operation done in C don't have this memory bandwith problem, so I don't buy the memory acessing problem

Comment: Interesting, here it takes 0.2s, 0.02s, and 0.01s respectively for those three operations.  Sure, my machine seems to be faster than yours, but the astype() operation certainly doesn't take anywhere near as long as the multiplication.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you use `imgarray = imgarray.astype('B')`, you get a copy of the array, cast to the specified type. This requires extra memory allocation, even though you immediately flip imgarray to point to the newly allocated array.

If you use `imgarray.view('uint8')`, then you get a view of the array. This uses the same data except that it is interpreted as `uint8` instead of `imgarray.dtype`.
(`np.dot` returns a `uint32` array, so after the `np.dot`, `imgarray` is of type `uint32`.)

The problem with using `view`, however, is that a 32-bit integer becomes viewed as 4 8-bit integers, and we only care  about the value in the last 8-bits. So we need to skip to every 4th 8-bit integer. We can do that with slicing:

`imgarray.view('uint8')[:,::4]`

IPython's %timeit command shows there is a significant speed up doing things this way:

```
In [37]: %timeit imgarray2 = imgarray.astype('B')
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 us per loop

In [39]: %timeit imgarray3 = imgarray.view('B')[:,::4]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.64 us per loop
```

Comment: Can I save this view to a file

Comment: @shodanex: Yes, you could use np.save(). See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: @shodanex: For other format options, see also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/routines.io.html

Comment: it is then implicitly architecture-dependent, since which slice to use depends on endianness.

Comment: @kaizer.se: Yes, that's true. Do you know a nice way to make the code non-architecture-dependent?

Comment: Obviously this also doesn't work when converting float to int.

Comment: @ubuntu What qualifies as “nice” depends on taste. But at least it is possible to cater for little and big endian architectures alike. Query the dtype's byteorder and create the view with the np.ndarray constructor's offset argument set appropriately.